# Insert another cell value into an IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, google-sheets, concatenation

I have an IF function and wish to include a variable string into the calculation.

Here is the standard function in B2

```
=iferror(if(D2>=A2,"Your target has been reached",""))
```

I need to insert the value of C2 (which can either be >-,<=,=) between the D2/A2 values. So in theory it would be something like this

```
=iferror(if(D2,C2,A2),"Your target has been reached",""))
```

I have tried with CONCAT, INDIRECT with no success. Any ideas on inserting a cell value into a function?

**EDIT**
Here is an example in a Sheet, so at the moment the logical operator is manually entered into the formula at B2. I wish to get the value of C2 inserted into the B2 function

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w1tkY8yTLgbSP4zw0bLSb4Y3PIXLPTImWsARUznf5R0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to insert the value of E2 (which can either be >-,<=,=) between the B2/C2 values

To get the string value in column C to act as the **operator** between column A and column D,

1. A mentioned previously, you could concatenate the three together and use the EVALUATE function.
2. Concatenate the operator and second value together and use the resulting formula in a COUNTIF.

   ```
   =IF(COUNTIF(D3, C2&A3), "Your target has been reached", "")
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. I have done an example in G Sheets, and edited my cell references above.

Answer (score 2):

This one is tricky. You can use EVALUATE function, however it does not work directly in the spreadsheet. So assuming we have structure like this:

```
| A | B | C |     D      | E |

| 1 | < | 3 | =A1&A2&A3  |   |
```

While being in cell **A2** add to name manager range "Result" with formula

```
=EVALUATE($D1)
```

Than just place in **E1** formula `=IF(Result,"Your target has been reached","")`

For more comprehensive description regarding `EVALUATE` function please refer to [this](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function) link.

Comment: Evaluate doesn't exist in Google Sheets, do you know of an option in Google Sheets where this could work?

Comment: @Jeeped provided interesting solution - it will probably work for you.